Got dependencies! 7 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints
[appname] flutter pub get --no-example
Resolving dependencies...
Downloading packages...
collection 1.18.0 (1.19.0 available)
http_parser 4.0.2 (4.1.0 available)
leak_tracker 10.0.4 (10.0.5 available)
leak_tracker_flutter_testing 3.0.3 (3.0.5 available)
material_color_utilities 0.8.0 (0.12.0 available)
meta 1.12.0 (1.15.0 available)
test_api 0.7.0 (0.7.3 available)
Got dependencies!
what can i do to update this all i do everything but sdk still not allow me to use meta 1.15.0
pub update major force
delete publock
i am newby sorry for stupid question and thank for help

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

It have no error flutter just recommend to update package. No need to do something about your package
